# Styling a select box by hiding it under a text box

Tags: html, css, z-index, css-position, html-select

Obviously it's not really possible to style a select box completely and thus I recall reading about a method some time back where you could style a text box for example and then hide the select box underneath it.

I tried this out just now with `absolute positioning` and using `z-index`; however as you might expect when you click on the text box you don't see the drop down select options.

Is this method really possible or not? If so, how?

If it's not, are there any non-javascript methods out there that will work across all browsers?

**Edit:**

Here is some example code..

```
<div class="cats">
    <input type="text" name="cat_show" value="All Categories" readonly="readonly" />
    <select name="cat">
        <option value="all">All Categories</option>
        <option value="cat1">Cat 1</option>
        <option value="cat2">Cat 2</option>
        <option value="cat3">Cat 3</option>
        <option value="cat4" class="last">Cat 4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header .nav .misc .search .search_holder .cats {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#header .nav .misc .search .search_holder .cats input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 111px;
    height: 25px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    background: url('../images/search-cats-bg.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
    font-family: Roboto, Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #b2b2b2;
    cursor: default;
    z-index: 3;
}

#header .nav .misc .search .search_holder .cats select {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;    
    width: 119px;
    height: 29px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    font-family: Roboto, Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: url('../images/form-text-bg.png') 0 0 repeat-x;
    color: #b2b2b2;
    z-index: 2;
}

#header .nav .misc .search .search_holder .cats select option {
    padding-top: 5px;
}

#header .nav .misc .search .search_holder .cats select option.last {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post some code, or use http://jsfiddle.net/ to show us an example? Thanks.

Comment: Uhm..now i understand a little more :) You really only want HTML+CSS? That way, you can't completely style the Select Box, but there are of course workarounds: you could put the select into a div that is a little shorter, with overflow:hidden, and position the select box so that the arrow is hidden. Then, the remaining are the options, and you can style them easily :) @brett

Comment: @ErenorPaz Not a bad idea, though I guess some JS of some kind would still be required as the "arrow" wouldn't be part of the select field but would need to be opened when clicked.

Comment: of course: i'm not sure what you need can be completely done without Javascript. You can, thought, use a plugin like Jquery to make sure it will work with the most of the browsers out there.  @Brett

Comment: Yeah..... guess I'll have to resort to some JS. Thanks though! :)

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/ :)

Answer (score 0):

You use this jquery code

```
$(function(){
   $("#YourTextBoxId").focus(function(){
      $("#YourDropDownName").hide();
   })
})
```